# Can someone help me visualize what's happening in this Recordset loop?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, adodb

I'm currently coding in ASP for the first time, and have arrived at ADO. Let's say I have a query that is as follows:

```vb
SQL = "SELECT President FROM Testing"
```

And the table is as follows:

```
President
------------------
George Washington
John Adams
Thomas Jefferson
James Madison
James Monroe
```

The code I originally got from W3 is as follows:

```vb
For Each x In recordset.fields                              
    Response.Write(x.name)
    Response.Write(" = ")
    Response.Write(x.value & "<br>")
Next
```

But then it only returns:

```vb
President = George Washington
```

when I expected the whole table. It wasn't until I changed it to this from W3:

```vb
Do Until Recordset.EOF
    For Each x In recordset.fields                              
        Response.Write(x.name)
        Response.Write(" = ")
        Response.Write(x.value & "<br>")
    Next
    Response.Write("<br>")
    Recordset.MoveNext
Loop
```

That I get all of the names. Can someone help me visualize what's happening? I figured in the first piece of code, it would loop through the table until it gave me all of the names, but that wasn't the case. Pretty much, "For each recordset field, write the column name + equal sign + the value of the current row, then move on to the **next** row."

Or is it because I'm not understanding recordset properly?

Comment: Your first piece of code is looking at all the columns (aka fields in a RecordSet). If you want all the rows you have to look at the rows like you did in the second piece of code. A recordset is like Excel. It has rows and columns. If you only iterate the columns that is all you are going to get.

Comment: The `Fields` collection contains all the columns for that one record to get the next record along with it's accompanying columns you need to call the `MoveNext()` method, this moves the `AbsolutePosition` to the next record and updates the `Fields` collection *(variations based on provider)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As both [myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29258583/can-someone-help-me-visualize-whats-happening-in-this-recordset-loop#comment46719832_29258583) and [@sean-lange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29258583/can-someone-help-me-visualize-whats-happening-in-this-recordset-loop#comment46719704_29258583) have *already* pointed out in the comments above.

The `Fields` collection contains the columns for the current record only.

## So we have the Columns what about the Rows?

The `ADODB.Recordset` object contains both column and row data how do we get to the rows? Recordsets behave differently dependant on the cursor used but for this let's assume that we can move back and forth.

[@sean-langes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3813116/sean-lange) analogy is best, think of the `ADODB.Recordset` as an Excel Spreadsheet and the `Fields` collection is the columns across the top. If we tab from left to right across a row we only see data for that current row, to get the next row we have to move down the spreadsheet. The same is true for an `ADODB.Recordset` which is provided by the `MoveNext()` method. This tells the cursor to move to the next record and repopulate the `Fields` collection with the row values.

The second example you posted is a common technique used to iterate through the records in a `ADODB.Recordset`. Let's break -down what that code is doing;

This begins the loop and tell's Classic ASP to continue looping the contained code until the cursor has reached the `.EOF` (End of File) equal to `True`. This signals the cursor has past the final record and there is no more records to process by calling `MoveNext()`.

```vb
Do While Not recordset.EOF
```

During the loop we have a current record so while this is the case we can access the `Fields` collection and enumerate the data.

```vb
    For Each x In recordset.fields
```

The key is `MoveNext` which moves the cursor to the next record and repopulates the collections such as `Fields` associated to the current record.

```vb
    recordset.MoveNext
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `For Each` loop enumerates the fields of the current record (vulgo "row") of your recordset. You need another loop to [move](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677527%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the "current record" indicator through the recordset to iterate over all records/rows. That's what

```vb
Do Until recordset.EOF   'stop after the last record
  ...                    'do stuff
  recordset.MoveNext     'move to the next record
Loop
```

does.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I have little experience with VB. The reason the first piece of code only returns George Washington is because the pointer is not advanced in the recordset. The pointer is fixed on record 0 (working in arrays) and therefore, I believe, returning George Washington 5 times. In the second example, the pointer is moved after every iteration (Recordset.MoveNext) and therefore will print all the names.

The first code is doing: Response.Write(x[0]) 5 times.
The second code is doing: Response.Write(x[0]) *move pointer* Response.Write(x[1]]), etc

Comment: Don't confuse [tag:VB] and [tag:VBScript] this is [tag:asp-classic] using VBScript.

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL = "SELECT President FROM Testing"

Set objRs = objConnection.Execute(SQL)

Do While Not objRs .EOF
    Response.Write objRs("President") & "<br>"
    objRs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: Consider adding an explanation as to how the helps the OP.